# Meaning of “give a pony”

Tags: phrases, expressions

I came across this phrase while reading an [article by Paul Krugman](http://krugman.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/02/25/european-crisis-realities/) on the New York Times website. Here's the quotation (emphasis added):

> … non-GIPSI [*the group of Eurozone nations – Greece, Italy, Portugal, Spain, Ireland – that are grappling with the debt crisis, my note*] European leaders should realize that what the GIPSIs really need is a general European reflation. So let's hope that they get this, and also **give each of us a pony**.

Now, I understand that this is a sort of witty remark, but I cannot figure out what he's referring to. I know that there's a horse breed named “Gypsy”, but I suspect there may be another reference—an idiomatic one, perhaps—I don't know of.

Comment: I guess he means the supply of money by saying "pony" - small part of it! He says what Europe needs now is reflation and he hopes to get a pony of that!

Comment: Incidentally, does Krugman think *GIPSIs* is less offensive than the usual *PIIGS*?

Comment: Both are obviously used in a derogatory sense, but that seems to me as being more a sort of memory trick. However, could anyone come up with a less disparaging acronym? (By the way, I'm Italian myself, but this designation doesn't annoy me that much. They're only economists, after all.)

Comment: @TimLymington I found PIIGS extremely offensive and GIPSI much less offensive or maybe not offensive at all.

Comment: Pretty weak attempt at humour trying to link the 'pony' phrase and traditional and stereotypical views on Romany folk. May be he couldn't make his PIIGS and 'purse out of a sow's ear' theme work. GIPSI was the fallback choice.

Comment: At first I too thought of something along these lines. But it would have made a pretty mean, politically incorrect (and weak, as you said) witticism, which is not like Krugman. I would rather go with Lunivore's explanation below.

Comment: And here I thought a pony was a measure of hard liquor, like being ⅔ of a jigger.

Comment: picture here: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?IwantaPony

Comment: fwiw: You've missed the actual american idiom. The Urban Dictionary reference, while valid, does not actually tell you anything about the idiom. It's actually quite customary for there to be an attribution that a young girl demands a pony for her birthday when she belongs to a wealthy family, and is seen as an unfair, albeit commonly understood as normal, gift/demand.

Comment: Also note that in the five+ hours since I wrote my previous comment, much discussion has taken place and the above comment is now out of sorts with the results.

Comment: I thought 'a pony' was a slang term for 25 UK pounds.  A 'score' for 20, 'pony' for 25, a 'monkey' for 500, and 'a grand' for 1,000.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For me, the phrase "Give each of us a pony" means literally "give each of us a gift of a horse."

Ponies, as far as I know, are regarded as a status symbol among certain circles. (Imagine a young girl in a well-to-do family requesting her father this for a birthday present).

So, for me, saying "give each of us a pony" is equivalent to "give each of us a Jaguar/ yacht/ swimming pool etc.," which was meant with humor.

Comment: Are you allowed to look a pony in the mouth? :)

Comment: Yes :-D Especially if it's an answer here. But what do you think of my answer, tchrist?

Comment: To be honest, "give us each a pony" makes me think of the rantings of a pretentious teenage girl wanting her own young horse that she can learn to ride as it gets older, as a sign of wealth and prestige. To me your answer was the most correct, even tho the asker went with the most upvoted question, without understanding actual American idioms.

Comment: Thanks for saying that, jcolebrand. That particular image is very familiar to me as well :-)

Comment: @jcolebrand I thought that Lunivore's was the best answer before it got the upvotes it has now. Cool Elf's answer is fine too, but I personally prefer the one I picked.

Comment: Ok, well I just wanted to make sure that you realized that you are missing the actual correct answer based on idioms, and instead are going with "oh look, urban dictionary". Since you asked what the idiom was, and all that.

Comment: Uhm, I didn't pick that answer because of the reference to Urban Dictionary: I'm not 15 any more. I don't like your argumentative tone, but I think I'll come around to your point of view.

Comment: A surprising turn of events and I'm a bit flattered. Thanks for reconsidering, Giorgiomastro! :-)

Comment: jcolebrand was right: this answer is more accurate, as it makes a specific reference to that “spoiled brat” imagery. Sorry for overlooking it, Cool Elf.

Comment: The way I see it, the goal for all of us here is to arrive at the most accurate info possible, so that it may serve as reference to future learners. We managed to arrive at that through trial-and-error. So I say good job to all of us

Comment: Just as a note, I did find another reference to the idiom which I added in the comments - Urban Dictionary isn't the only use. And I'd come across the idiom before which is how I knew to look it up.

Comment: ...and I've added some more research, since "oh look, urban dictionary" doesn't seem to rock your boat, @jcolebrand.

Comment: "a pony", is an idiom that means "unrealistic wish". See the other answers and http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?IwantaPony

Comment: Right, Lunivore. A sharper take on the exact word "pony" could also help more non-native speakers get a firm grasp of the expression. This doesn't mean we couldn't appreciate your answer. In fact, I know the appeal that your answer had was the way it pointed out the impracticality of the concept

Comment: What I miss from this answer is exactly that emphasis on the implied impossibility of the fact.

Comment: I don't understand @Giorgiomastrò, how there is an implied argumentative tone in my text, when I merely used text, and only said that you completely overlooked the think that you asked for. Please don't read an argumentative tone into text that does not have an argument present. When I came to this question, an answer with well over 20 upvotes that was incorrect had the checkmark, and I wanted, for better or for worse, for an accurate and explanatory answer to have the checkmark for future visitors. Objective Q & A. That means definitive answers. Cheers.

Comment: You're making things difficult for me. In fact, three answers are fine (Cool Elf's, Lunivore's and Jay's), but I've already changed my mind once, so I would definitively go with this one. @jcolebrand That was the impression I got from you—that “oh look, Urban Dictionary” made me look like a brainless teenager. Anyway, I'm not going to make too much of it: you made me realize I was overlooking something important, and I thank you.

Comment: I never intended to "make things difficult for you". Please don't read that into this. I merely wanted to point out that as an apparent non-native English speaker, that the accepted answer did not contribute. I'm actively searching (without much success) and more historically rooted answer for where this came from. I've known the phrase for at least 25 years (I'm only 32) and feel it's much closer to a couple hundred years old, but am not entirely sure.

Comment: @jcolebrand The first part of my previous comment wasn't meant for you and was something like “Oh gosh, you (guys) are giving me so many choices…”.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the clarification. As I stated, I just want to help you get the best answer I can.

Comment: I see. Sorry for being so touchy, but writing on the internet has its own downsides, as it's more difficult to understand the real intentions of those you talk with.

Comment: To add to the discussion, I've found that the screenplay for THE LITTLE PRINCESS from 1938 by 20th Century Fox, Directed by Walter Lang, Screenplay by E. Hill, W. Ferris, contains a reference to a spoiled rich girl getting a pony from her father who is away, as an appeasement, even when she doesn't realize it, and then there is the character of Veruca Salt from the 1968 novel Charlie and the Chocolate Factory who demands that her father buy her a squirrel ... that turns into her demanding a pony. However, both of these premise were well entrenched in the mindset of literature, I believe.

Answer (score 62):

"I want a pony" is a slang phrase, usually used in reply to someone's request for something impossible.

From the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=I%20want%20a%20pony):

> "We want a copy protection solution that's 100% unbreakable."
>
> "Yes, and I want a pony."

In this context, it reads to me that while the author would very much like a solution to the Eurozone crisis, he doesn't believe it's actually possible. I don't think it's anything to do with *a pony* meaning £25.

Here are two more examples:

> [Health care sectors get funding restraint… and a pony](http://diablogue.org/2012/02/15/drummond-report-health-care-sectors-get-funding-restraint-and-a-pony/).
>
> [...where everyone can get all the health care they want for almost no money. And a pony.](http://angry-economist.russnelson.com/and-a-pony.html)

After a little more research, it turns out that the origin of the meme may have come from Calvin and Hobbes (search for "and a pony" [in this page](http://www.chemistrydaily.com/chemistry/Calvin_and_Hobbes)).

> "Then my hundred friends and I would go do something fun, and leave Calvin all alone! Ha! …and as long as I'm dreaming, I'd like a pony." - Susie

I'm probably familiar with it because it's been [popularised in IT by Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/and-a-pony.html), a well-known author, blogger and speaker.

Comment: I like your explanation. Krugman's style includes lots of quips and ironical remarks, so I think you got it right.

Comment: I agree. Krugman seems to be saying that the likelihood that European leaders will realise what he has suggested as the solution is as likely that they'll give him and his readers ponies.

Comment: Found a similar use here: http://angry-economist.russnelson.com/and-a-pony.html

Comment: I quite agree an NYT writer would never allude to the UK (Cockney) slang "pony=£25" like that. I imagine it derives from the idea that indulgent (and rich) parents might give their daughter a pony for her birthday - as picked up by Hasbro's [My little pony](http://www.hasbro.com/mylittlepony/en_GB/)

Comment: Found another, so I've edited the post to include them.

Comment: This is a correct answer. See also http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?IwantaPony

Comment: Thanks @christoffer-hammarstrom. Looks like I may be heading for my 2nd populist badge!

Comment: I'm moving this discussion to chat as I don't believe it adds to the answer (which I still believe to be useful) - [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3743/discussion-between-lunivore-and-jcolebrand)

Answer (score 24):

It's common in America to talk about a child wanting a pony as a request or demand for an extravagant gift. Little girls especially traditionally see a pony as the ultimate toy. In my own family, for example, since my daughter was old enough to understand money, any time we had an unexpected expense she would jokingly say, "That money could have gone to my pony fund", or when I got a pay raise she would say, "That can go to the pony fund." Of course few families really buy a pony for their child: it's too expensive and impractical. Where would the average family keep a pony in an urban apartment?

So Krugman is concluding his article by saying what he hopes European leaders will do to solve the fiscal crisis. If he stopped there, the sentence would be understood to mean that he thinks that this is a reasonable expectation, that he thinks it likely that they will, in fact, do this. But by tacking on "and also give each of us a pony", he's saying that, like a parent whose child asks for a pony for her birthday, they will likely view his suggestion as a totally unrealistic, fantasy request.

Comment: This is a correct answer. See also http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?IwantaPony

Comment: Little girls saying, "I want a pony," regardless of their families' ability to pay for one, was a trope in a lot of material, from what I can recall from my childhood.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe what Krugram really wants is a squirrel.

I see it as Krugman making a metaphor.  Krugman is comparing GIPSI to a spoiled child (like Veruca Salt of "Charlie and the Chocolate Factory" fame), and non-GIPSI to Mr. Salt.  Veruca is making an unreasonable demand and Mr. Salt wants to accommodate to keep Veruca happy, but it is not clear Mr. Salt can.

We can take Krugman as Veruca's brother.  If Veruca gets a pony, he wants one too.

Source:  http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0003692/quotes

Veruca Salt: Daddy, I want a squirrel. Get me one of those squirrels, I want one!

Mr. Salt: Veruca dear, you have many marvelous pets.

Veruca Salt: All I've got at home is one **pony** and two dogs and four cats and six bunny rabbits and two parakeets and three canaries and a green parrot and a turtle, and a silly old hamster! I WANT a SQUIRREL!

Mr. Salt: All right, pet. Daddy'll get you a squirrel just as soon as he possibly can.

Veruca Salt: But I don't want any old squirrel! I want a *trained* squirrel!

Mr. Salt: [wearily] Very well. Mr. Wonka? How much do you want for one of these squirrels? Name your price.

Willy Wonka: Oh they're not for sale. She can't have one.

Veruca Salt: Daddy!

Willy Wonka: [imitating Mr. Salt] I'm sorry, darling. Mr. Wonka's being unreasonable.

Veruca Salt: Daddy, I want another **pony**.

Comment: Perfect quote to illustrate the pretention of the request. Good job.

Comment: No sweeter way to drive a point than quoting from Charlie and the Chocolate Factory. Thanks guys! :-)

Comment: This does not really answer the question.

Comment: Though this seems to nail the provenance of the idea, please make it an actual answer, adding some explanation.

Comment: The idea of actually _getting_ a pony is from "Gone with the Wind" (a spoiled daughter gets a pony).

Comment: But of _asking_ for a pony @Mitch? (or more specifically, demanding a pony)

Comment: @jcolebrand: The given answer here sounds like a it is answering for 'asking'.

Comment: @Mitch I know, and I was trying to find an earlier reference, and can't. :-\ Which sucks, because I'm sure it's older than Charlie and the Chocolate Factory.

Comment: @jcolebrand: OK, I have no real idea, but since sarcasm wasn't invented until Raoul Dahl, it just seems right that this was the first. Except for maybe Shakespeare.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that as long as you're wishing for the impossible, you might as well wish for other desirable things (such as a pony) too. So Krugman is sarcastically pointing out that "a general European reflation" is wishful thinking.

This use of "... and a pony" to point sarcastically to wishful economic and political thinking comes from Belle Waring's 2004 blog post "[If Wishes Were Horses, Beggars Would Ride -- A Pony!](http://examinedlife.typepad.com/johnbelle/2004/03/if_wishes_were_.html)"

> I'd like to note, though, that [Josh] Chafetz is selling himself short. You see, wishes are totally free. It's like when you can't decide whether to daydream about being a famous Hollywood star or having amazing magical powers. Why not -- be a famous Hollywood star with amazing magical powers! Along these lines, John [Holbo] has developed an infallible way to improve any public policy wishes. You just wish for the thing, plus, wish that everyone would have their own pony! So, in Chafetz' case, he should not only wish that Bush would say a lot of good things about democracy-building and fighting terrorism in a speech written for him by a smart person, he should also wish that Bush should actually mean the things he says and enact policies which reflect this, and he should wish that everyone gets a pony. See?

John Holbo got the pony idea from a [*Calvin and Hobbes*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calvin_and_Hobbes) cartoon by [Bill Watterson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Watterson), first published in 1987 and [described here](http://www.reemst.com/calvin_and_hobbes/stripsearch?q=suzy%20&%20wish%20&%20pony&search=normal&start=0&details=422):

> Susie wipes a tear from her eye. She wonders why Calvin is so mean. She wishes she had a hundred friends, then she wouldn't care what Calvin said. She goes on to say she and her hundred friends would go do something fun and leave Calvin all alone. But then, Susie sits down. She says that as long as she's dreaming, she also wants a pony.

Answer (score 0):

Another meaning is in the sense:

> "I don't give a pony."

Which means: "I don't care."

Or

> "That looks pony, mate!"

Which means: That looks rubbish, mate!

Or

> "He was talking pony."

Which means: He was talking nonsense.

In all the above words, the word "pony" is a term for its excrement, pejorative as in the expletive, "sh*t". For example, for the first example: "I don't give a sh*t".

**References:**

- [Talking pony - Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Talking%20Pony)
- Personal experience of others talking in this way.

Comment: That may well be a legitimate use of 'give a pony' but it is irrelevant in meaning to the context given.

Comment: +1 Indeed. In that case my answer serves to give value by offering possible misinterpretations that could occur, rather than clarifying the context given. In other words: interlocutor1: "Should I give a pony?" interlocutor2: "Yes, I think you should" (misinterpreting interlocutor 1's answer as being a request for advice on material reimbursement, when actually what they were saying is: should I care?).